# Decode non-ascii characters from numpy object

Tags: python, numpy, unicode, decode, encode

```
import numpy as np

sentence = ['世界']

a = np.array(sentence, dtype=object).reshape(-1)

b = [sentence for sentence in np.char.decode(a.astype(np.bytes_), 'UTF-8')]
```

I was trying to convert a `numpy.object` back to string, but it didn't work for non-ascii characters.
Error was

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: `b = a.tolist()` doesn't work?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, e.g. what would a desired result look like?

Comment: Try encoding your list `sentence = [x.encode() for x in sentence]` or the suggestion by @AndrejKesely which is dead simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand what `np.object` is. It just means "other python stuff" (by opposition to other data types, that are converted in numpy, without their internal python wrapping: only the array is wrapped in a python object, not all its content. So, an array of 1000 short int, use only 2000 bytes in memory. And can efficiently be iterated by numpy's internal C code, without having to bother about python internal representation of data)

See the difference

```py
T=np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.uint32)
Tb=T.tobytes()
Tb
# b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00'
len(Tb)
# 12
np.frombuffer(Tb, dtype=np.uint32)
# [1,2,3]
```

Of course, the last line may seem stupid. But it proves what is stored in numpy's memory: directly the values of the 3 int32. Which also shows by just watching `Tb`: we see the 12 bytes, 1,0,0,0 (so 1, on 32 bits, little endian — at least on my machine, probably on yours too), 2,0,0,0 (so 2), 3,0,0,0.

You can decode also with `struct`

```py
import struct
struct.unpack('iii', Tb)
```

So, nothing surprising here: when we create an array on 3 int32, it contains 12 bytes, that are the 12 bytes representing the values of those int32.

Now, compare that to this

```py
U=np.array([1,2,3], dtype=object)
Ub=U.tobytes()
Ub 
# b' n\x95\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@n\x95\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`n\x95\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
len(Ub)
U.dtype.itemsize # or U.strides[-1]
# 8
```

We see that each number is encoded with 8 bytes, so 24 bytes all together.
But watching `Ub`, that doesn't seem to be just the int64 encoding of 1 2 3. Let's check

```py
struct.unpack('lll', Ub)
# or
np.frombuffer(Ub, dtype=np.uint64)
# (9793056, 9793088, 9793120)
```

So, nothing to do with `(1,2,3)`. Or...

```py
id(1)
# 9793056
id(2)
# 9793088
id(3)
# 9793120
```

Likewise with your own array

```py
struct.unpack('l', a.tobytes())
# (140450860495472,)
id(sentence[0])
# 140450860495472
```

So, this is what `object` means from numpy point of view: id of python object are stored. A pointer to those python object, if your wish. That means that this is opaque for numpy. It can't understand what is in a `object` array. It can't perform any operation on it. It is not encoded, nor does it need to be decoded in any way. It is just the id of the object, that only python (not numpy) can understand. The only thing numpy can do with it, is give it back to you as you had given it to it.

So, of course the advantage is that it can store anything. The drawback is that you can basically do nothing with it.

But, well, now that I made clear what is that type, there is no decoding to do. Your string (a python string, that is a "pointer" to the python object containing that string) is stored, incomprehensible for numpy, but as is. And when you get it back (for example with a simple `a[0]`) it is still the same string for python

```py
a[0]
# '世界'
```

## Unicode and utf8/decode

Since you flagged the question `unicode`, `decode`, ... it may worth seing where utf8 encoding, and unicode lies here.

I could also, instead of using a int based example, have compared to `<U2` type, but that add a complexity

```
V=np.array(sentence)
Vb=V.tobytes()
V.dtype.itemsize
# 4
np.frombuffer(Vb, dtype=np.uint32)
# array([19990, 30028], dtype=uint32)
```

Unsurprisingly, 19990 is unicode for `世` [ref here](https://wutils.com/unicode/19990)

So what are those 19990, 30028 to the encoded string
See

```
utf8 = np.frombuffer(sentence[0].encode(), dtype=np.uint8)
utf8
# array([228, 184, 150, 231, 149, 140], dtype=uint8)
[bin(x) for x in utf8]
# ['0b11100100', '0b10111000', '0b10010110', '0b11100111', '0b10010101', '0b10001100']
```

Based on utf8 standard, we see that the first bytes starts with 3 `111` followed by a `0`. So it is a 3 bytes code. The 2 following bytes start indeed with `10`, continuing the 3 bytes code. Altogether, the 16 bits are the last 4 of the 1st byte, and the last 6 of the 2 following ones. So
`0100111000010110`

Which is number

```py
int('0100111000010110', 2)
# 19990
```

Likewise, the 3 next bytes,of course, are utf8 encoding of number 30028

So, `sentence[0].encode()` is utf-8 encoding of the string, that is `utf-8` encoding of unicode values. What is stored inside numpy array, when using `<U` dtype are the unicode values (without utf8 encoding, that is with a fixed, 32 bits, size)

So, in other words, when using `<U2` dtype, strings are encoded (in uint32 numbers, representing unicode code of the string characters). Numpy does understand what it means, and can act on it. Not much, because numpy is not very well adapted for string processing. As the `num` of its name implies, numpy's role is more about numbers, but still, the string data are encoded in the array, not just pointers to opaque python reference to a python object that happens to be a string, but that only python knows about. Which is what happens with `object`

So long story short, when you encode things (number, strings, whatever) in `object`, you can't use any numpy function on them. But you don't need to do anything to decode them. They are just raw reference to python objects. When you use another `dtype`, then things are encoded in a way that make sense to numpy, on which numpy can work. But need a conversion (usually taking care of by numpy's constructor and getters) back and forth, from python's internal representation of things, and numpy's.